# What is our elevator pitch?

Tags: discussion

Realised we hadn't written an elevator pitch for Security SE ([as per the 7 essential Meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/))

From that page,

> the elevator pitch is a brief sentence
>   that describes what your site is
>   about. Every word counts!

What would your 1 minute elevator pitch consist of?

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Might you want to add the `featured` tag to this?

Comment: @Iszi - yes, yes I might :-)

Comment: +1, but elevator pitch is usually constrained to 30 seconds... :)

Comment: @AviD - erm....I have a very slow lift?.... :-) Good point.

Comment: hehe... or a very tall building :D

Comment: @AviD Elevators are for the weak.You have exactly as much time as the staircase allows.

Comment: @Scott - and Daleks (well, old school Daleks anyway)

Comment: @ScottPack ever since Aerosmith's song, I'm still hoping every time... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two biggest issues with communities within the Information Security field are:

1. Fragmentation between code guys, systems people, forensics, policy, etc
2. Closed community with strict sharing guidelines that, while fostering frank exchanges *within* the community, make it difficult to work with others in the field.

To that end, we finally have a place for information security conversations to happen **Out In The Open**. By specifically including every specialty, we've managed to create an environment where we can learn from each other. This keeps the specialists cognizant of the happenings elsewhere in the field without alienating the generalists.

Whether it is professionals helping professionals, professionals helping users, or users helping professionals -- everybody wins.

Comment: I think this is a great intro. But, perhaps a bit too long for an elevator pitch...

Comment: @avid perhaps "Information security Q&A for both specialists and generalists, in the open?"

Answer (score 5):

> Savvy, friendly information security advice for
>   professionals, from appsec to crypto.

Or, if the elevator ride is a bit longer:

> Nicely integrated and effective
>   information security Q&A site, with
>   expert advice, but friendly to
>   aspiring professionals.  Application
>   security, risk management, crypto,
>   penetration testing and much more.

Comment: +1 for that first 'sound bite' length pitch.